# Pandas: How to add up values, only if they have the same number

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a list of orders. Every order has a order-number (1, 2, 3, 4...). If a customer ordered more then 1 Item, the order-number will be the same.

[image]

Now I'd like to sumarize the prices oft the Items in a new column if the order number is the same. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What does `sumarize` mean? Add them up?

Comment: Hi @Ynjxsjmh. Yes, add them up

Comment: If so, just `groupby('order')['price'].sum()`.

Comment: Thank you @Ynjxsjmh! Ist there a possibility to write the answer (sum) in a new column?

Comment: I'd tried this one: 

df.insert(loc=17,
          column='Summe',
          value= df.groupby('Order #')['Price_per_QTY'].sum())
But the result ist only NaN

Comment: would the other columns be exact same value for the same order #? because i dont think you can combine the row into a single one without handling columns such as "items name" as well

Comment: @AkshaySehgal. the other columns could be left that way. I just want to have the total value of the order somewhere.
For an order with 5 products, it can also be 5 lines at the end.

Comment: do duplicate order numbers are fine? ie, multiple rows with same order number? or `summarize` means you want one row for each order, along with its total?

Comment: well in that case, @Ynjxsjmh has answered your question correctly.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal They are only duplicate on `order`, the item name and price are not duplicate.

Comment: yes i mentioned that in my first comment as well. i have updated my last comment to be clearer.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal: Yes you are right. I probably said it wrong.

Duplicate order numbers are fine.

I would just like to have a column in which the total is added up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) on grouped by, which will return a Series with the same index as the original dataframe. Sum value of each group is assigned to each group index.

```py
df['sum'] = df.groupby('Order')['Price'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: that doesnt solve the issue completely though. OP has not been clear on how they would handle the other columns. `transform` will result in the same number of duplicated rows, instead of combining the multiple ones to a single row.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal If OP want to add sum to a new column, I just guess what he wants is all the same order has a same sum.

Comment: yea you are correct but that doesnt change the fact that 5 rows of same order # will remain 5 rows after the transform.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal That's true, but OP doesn't reveal any information about the change of row.

Comment: thats exactly my point. As i mention before, OP has not been clear on how they would handle other columns. its best practice to ask and resolve such queries before answering OPs question, which in this case is still unclear.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Thank you and I will take care next time to make sure OP has made the question clear.

Comment: It's my fault. Thank you guys. you are great!